# Как указать обработчик на Initialized для динамически создаваемого элемента?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Здравствуйте. Есть TreeView. Items заполняются через привязку данных. Как мне добавить к ним обработчик на Initialized?

Пробовал так

```
<EventSetter Event="Initialized" Handler="OnInit"/>
```

Но на этапе компиляции получаю "*Ошибка Событие "Initialized" отлично от RoutedEvent*"

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

XAML:

```
<TreeView>
   <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Tag="{Binding}" Orientation="Horizontal" Initialized="StackPanel_Initialized">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
            </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Обработчик:

```
private void StackPanel_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StackPanel sp = sender as StackPanel;
            User user = (User)sp.Tag;  //нужно проверить на null
            string Name = user.Name;
            int Age = user.Age;
        }
```

Comment: А разве инициализация корневого элемента шаблона полностью совпадает с инициализацией самого TreeViewItem? Я ведь в обработчике не выйду на TreeViewItem, потому что он еще не инициализирован, а мне нужен именно он.

Comment: Событие Initialized будет возникать с каждым новым экземпляром StackPanel, который, в свою очередь, будет создаваться с каждым новым элементом TreeViewItem. Но, вообще вместо Initialized лучше использовать событие Loaded.

Comment: Уточните, как вы хотите использовать TreeViewItem?

Comment: Мне нужно узнать некоторые свойства TreeViewItem. Например, число всех дочерних элементов его родителя, текущее положение на панели (координаты) и другие...

Comment: Если вам крайне принципиально получить именно TreeViewItem, то предложенный мною выше способ, очевидно, не подходит. Однако, координаты можно получить и у StackPanel (они будут такими же). Кроме того, некрасиво и  медленно получать родителей и потомков у визуального представления, коим является TreeView и его элементы.  Намного быстрее и гибче получать экземпляр, как я показывал в примере обработчика выше, и потом искать его в том, что у вас выступает в качестве BindingSource. Для удобства поиска и идентификации добавьте к каждому элементу иерархии уникальный ID.

Comment: Много чего придется переделывать тогда. К тому же я не собираюсь искать родителей визуального представления, я собираюсь искать родителя логического представления. А это уже другая история. А для удобства идентификации я вообще не оперирую TreeViewItem'ами, я работаю напрямую с XElement коими и являются все узлы дерева (конечно, они являются именно TreeViewItem в визуальном представлении, но мне это неинтересно). Данная же проблема (сабж) - частный случай. И решение должно быть без костылей. Оно просто по логике должно быть.